# Sum of a field and an array in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm having a collection with an array `an_array` and a field `a_field`. The array *can* consist of values (the array may be empty) which can also exist in `a_field`.

I want to create an aggregate function that sums up the number of values in either `a_field` or `an_array`.

*Edit: e.g. I want to count how many times `1` is used in `a_field` and `an_array`, etcetera.*

For example if I have some documents that looks like this:

```
{
  a_field: 1,
  an_array: [ 1, 3, 4 ],
},
{
  a_field: 3,
  an_array: [],
}
{
  a_field: 2,
  an_array: [ 1 ],
}
```

I'd like to see an output like this:

```
[ { _id: 1, a_count: 1, b_count: 2 }, { _id: 2, a_count: 1, b_count: 0 }, { _id: 3, a_count: 1, b_count: 1 }, { _id: 4, a_count: 0, b_count: 1 } ]
```

However I get an output like this:

```
[ { _id: 1, a_count: 1, b_count: 2 }, { _id: 3, a_count: 1, b_count: 1 }, { _id:4,  a_count: 1, b_count: 1 } ]
```

Which is incorrect as it's missing `_id` 2, and `_id` 4 has too many counts.

The problem I'm facing however is that when `an_array` is empty, I will not retrieve all counts properly if the array is empty, plus it gets the value of the `a_count` which doesn't always match up with the actual id (as can be seen in `_id` 4).

What I have so far is this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [
    { $match: { 
        a_field: { 
            $ne: null 
        } 
    } },

    { $group: { 
        _id: '$a_field', 
        a_count: { 
            $sum: 1 
        }, 
        an_array: { 
            $push: {
                an_array: '$an_array'
            }
        }
     } },

    { $project: {
        an_array: 1,
        a_count: 1
    } },

    { $unwind: '$an_array' },
    { $unwind: '$an_array.an_array' },

    { $group: {
        _id: '$an_array.an_array',
        b_count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        a_count: {
            $first: '$a_count'
        }
    } }, 
] );
```

I would really appreciate some input, as I'd love to do it in one single aggregate. At this point this has become more of a personal quest than an actual implementation. Thanks!

*Edit: I'm bound to MongoDB 2.6 for now.*

Comment: Why do use need to apply `$sum` to `a_field` if it is not an array? Also what is `_id` in the expected output?

Comment: The `_id` in the output is going to be one of the `an_array` values currently. That's what I expect as well, that I get a list of numbers with a sum. What do you mean why we need to apply `$sum`? If I want to keep count on the amount of times it's being added, that's the only way, no?

Comment: Actually, you've shown us 3 documents and in your expected output you have 4. Also if what you want is the distinct item in the `an_array` field and not equal to `a_field` then you are doing it wrong. Even if it's not distinct there is a better way to do this. You should consider to improve your question.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what it says. The output should contain the unique numbers used in the `a_field` and `an_array`. And if you think I'm doing it wrong, then I'd like to see a concrete example how I should do it instead please.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$size` for the array field, which is new to v2.6 you lucky boy!

Also I don't understand why you'd want to try and count the `$a_field` - there's always going to be one element as it's not an array - so this aggregation just includes what `$a_field` is as the `_id` in the result. you know that the count for `$a_field` will always be `1` as it's not an array:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    a_field: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}, {
 $group: {
    _id: '$a_field',
    an_array_size: {
      $size: '$an_array'
    }
  }
}])
```

Example console output:

```
> db.test.find({});
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57ada868700ca97222421d8b"),
  "a_field": 1,
  "an_array": [1, 3, 4]
}

> db.test.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    a_field: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}, {
 $group: {
    _id: '$a_field',
    an_array_size: {
      $size: '$an_array'
    }
  }
}])
{
  "result": [{
    "_id": 1,
    "an_array_size": 3
  }],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: I like your comment, but it isn't what I'm asking. If it is obscure, then sorry and I will revise my question. The reason why I `$sum` is because I want to know how _many_ times `1`, `2, etc are being used in the `a_field` and `an_array`. Is that more clear?

Comment: See what I gave as an example output.

Comment: Ahh much more clear! I'll update the answer, I did not see the _id:, 4 example.